# Cubic graphs without a perfect matching and a vertex incident to three bridges

Tags: graph-theory, perfect-matchings

The example shown below (courtesy of David Eppstein) is a common example of a cubic graph  **that admits no perfect matching**:

[image]
<sub>(source: [uci.edu](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Eeppstein/0xDE/cubic-unmatchable.png))</sub>

Are there other examples of cubic graphs that do not admit a perfect matching **and**, unlike the above example, do not contain a vertex that lies at the intersection of three bridges (i.e. an edge whose removal increases the number of connected components in the graph)?

Comment: Incidentally, the 16-vertex graph in the picture above has the **smallest  number of vertices among all cubic, edge-1-connected graphs without a perfect matching**. A proof for this statement was published in [Gary Chartrand, Donald L. Goldsmith, Seymour Schuster: *A sufficient condition for graphs with 1-factors*. Colloquium Mathematicum. Volume XLI, Fascicle 2, 1979](http://pldml.icm.edu.pl/pldml/element/bwmeta1.element.desklight-df88c7f0-e143-4ccf-bafd-ebbf9f6f40de). See Corollary 2a on p. 343 for the statement, and p. 341 for a picture.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Substitute your central vertex in your graph with a 3-cycle $abc$ so that the graph stays cubic. Now subdivide each edge in this 3-cycle. So we have new vertices $u$ connected to $a$ and $b$, $v$ connected to $b$ and $c$, $w$ connected to $c$ and $a$. Now add a final vertex $x$ and connect it to $u,v$ and $w$. This graph has exactly three bridges, none of which intersect the other at a vertex, and moreover has no perfect matching!

One result which relates the existence of a perfect matching in a cubic graph and its bridges is the following theorem of Petersen from "Die theorie der regularen graphen", Acta Math. 15
(1891), 163-220:

> **Theorem**: Every cubic graph with at most two bridges contains a perfect matching.

As well as this strengthening by Errera, "Du colorage des cartes", Mathesis 36 (1922), 56-60:

> **Theorem**: If all the bridges of a connected cubic graph $G$ lie on a single path of $G$, then $G$ has a perfect matching.

So your instinct is true, in the sense that if the graph has no perfect matching, its bridges do not lie on a path. However the example in the beginning of this answer shows that they are not necessarily incident at the same vertex.

Comment: Any two bridges lie on a path, so the second theorem is a strengthening of the first, not a converse.

Comment: Oops! It's fixed.

Answer (score -1):

I think there are no such graphs.

It was shown by Sumner and Las Vergnas (you can find the references here: http://mathsci.kaist.ac.kr/~sangil/pdf/2009claw.pdf) that a claw-free connected graph has a perfect matching (assuming even number of vertices, of course!).  An intersection of three bridges is clearly a claw.

Comment: @Felix: What you are saying is that: no perfect matching implies there is a claw. But a claw does not necessarily imply three bridges. So this does not address the question.

Comment: This is surely simple, but given that every vertex in a cubic graph has by definition three neighbours, how can any cubic graph be claw-free?

Comment: @Anthony, pick your favourite cubic graph and substitute each vertex with a triangle. You get a claw free cubic graph.

Comment: @Gjergji Zaimi: Oh, right, I had overlooked the **induced** subgraph part ;-) Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the wrong answer...